# Programmatically perform actions when an email message is received

Tags: office-js, office-addins

Using Web Based Outlook Add ins, I want to programmatically perform actions when an email message is received.

VSTO provides some events like NewMail/NewMailEx which gets trigger when one or more new items are received in the Inbox.
I am expecting similar kind of events or any other workaround for that.

I want to implement this functionality using Javscript based Outlook Add-ins.
-> If this is not supported yet then any idea whether this kind of thing has been planned for future ?

-> It should be ok if any workaround can work only on "outlook 365 client" and not OWA.

-> Is there any documentation available which has all the list of events supported by Outlook Add ins?

-> I read about Outlook REST API and Webhook and that may help for my requirement however, I am not sure how it would work for thousands of users.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they used to be called Web Hooks, but they are currently called [Delta queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/graph/delta-query-overview). There doesn't appear to be any restrictions in terms of user limits, but I do seem to recall there being *some* kind of limit. However, I cannot find any documentation on this. Regardless, this is exclusively a Graph technology, and nothing to do with Add-ins. You would need a Web application registered with Graph to perform these queries.

Comment: Thanks Eric! It doesn't seem to have any way with outlook add-in right? For this kind of requirement we have to rely on Microsoft Graph Delta Queries? My confusion is we can have thousands of users who can receive many emails at a given point of time so if we use Delta Queries then our subscribed app/service would get notification for all the users ? In case you have more info on this then it would really help. Thanks again!

Comment: Correct, the Office JS API doesn't have this functionality, only Graph (and EWS). Your web app will have to monitor all of the user mailbox folders that you have subscribed to, so it should be built to scale.

Comment: Currently the feature: launch add-in based on event like new email, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins 

[Outlook Add-ins Engineering Team]

Comment: Thanks Eric & Outlook Add-ins Engineering Team. I have posted my request here       https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/38204860-programmatically-perform-actions-when-an-email-mes